# How to reset a readonly static property?

Tags: c#, .net, static

I'm using a third party open source [Object Comparer util](http://objectcomparer.codeplex.com/) in a personal project through NuGet. The problem I have is that in the `Context` class there has a static read-only property(`Default`) that I need to be able to modify:

```
    public class Context :
    IContext
{

    private static Context _default;
    public static Context Default {
        get {
            if( _default==null )
                _default = GetDefaultContext();

            return _default;

        }
    }

    private Guid _id;
    public Guid Id { get { return _id; } }


    internal static Context GetDefaultContext() {
        //....Initializing the context here, e.g. assign a GUID
        var ctx = new Context();
        _id = GetGuid();
    }
```

In my `Compare` method I call it like this:

```
var myContext = Context.Default;
```

The problem is that I need to initialize the `Context` (e.g. different GUIDS) for every `Compare` call. 
Something like:

```
var myContext = Context.GetDefaultContext();
```

But unfortunately `GetDefaultContext` is marked as internal so I have no public access to it.

My question is how can I get around this limitation without modifying the source code and get a different initialized `Context` each time with different GUID? Because the way it is now I'm always getting the same Context initialized in the beginning, with same GUID.

Here is the [Source Code for Context](http://objectcomparer.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#ObjectComparer/Source/Configuration/Context.cs)..

Comment: Why not make it yourself? The constructor is public.

Comment: Make what myself? Sorry didn't get the idea

Comment: You can do `var myContext = new Context();` and then set some properties. You can't set the `Id`, so it will have an all-zeroes GUID. I don't know if this is an issue.

Comment: Yes that could be an issue Tim. I ended up using reflection to reset the _default field as @TheDutchMan suggested. It works great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you know the name of the private field why not set it to null and make the original code do the work itself?

```
Context context = new Context ();
context.GetType().GetField("_default", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic).SetValue(null, null);
```

Now whenever you call the default property again it will call `GetDefaultContext` again.

Comment: Clever idea, needs to be `BindingFlags.Static` instead of `BindingFlags.Instance` i believe. I'm testing it now

Comment: Other than that BindingFlags correction this worked for me. Thanks

Comment: No problem! I've changed the BindingFlags. I didn't realize it was a static field.